Semantic patch to add void argument to empty function declarations
Have a codebase full of functions that take no parameters omit the void argument which is producing around 500 warnings when I try to enable -Wextra.
I want to write a semantic patch for e.g. converting signatures like int fn() to int fn(void).
But this should obviously exclude calls to fn i.e. fn(); should not become fn(void).
Everything I've tried seems to either error or simply doesn't change anything.

Incidentally, under the newly published C23 standard, int fn(); actually does declare fn as taking no arguments, identically to int fn(void);.

Take the list of warnings and extract locations from them...

Are your function definitions consistently formatted?  For example, is the return type on the line before the function name and the start of the argument list?  If so, you simply need to look for identifiers in column 1 followed by () and either nothing else or by optional white space and an open brace.  I assume that no-one was silly enough to write the opening parenthesis on one line and the close parenthesis on the next.  Could there be comments like int *(/*void*/) to worry about?  If the code base is moderately consistent, you can do a lot with Perl-like regular expressions.

It's harder if you have functions that return pointers to functions (think of signal() in standard C).  But that's unlikely to be a common subspecies of function.  I've spent a decade on a multi-million line code base dealing with such issues.  A major problem was the number of K&R-style functions with arguments.   There are still ghettos where there are problems.  Those are no longer valid in C23 (whereas your int function() signatures become prototypes, though I'll still be writing int function(void) for a long while yet).

Upgrading to C23 would solve all your problems indeed... if you dare. It's still in some experimental stage and the compilers for it are brittle at best. But if sticking to a safe subset, it could perhaps be an option.

can you post a representative sample input and compiler output logs please.

I ended up solving this using the quickfix list and a macro in vim.

The following semantic patch will work
@@
type T;
identifier fn;
@@
  T
- fn()
+ fn(void)
  { ... }

When applied to this code:
int baz() { return 3; }

int main() {
  int var = baz();

  return baz();
}

Produces this result:
$ spatch --sp-file add_void.cocci code/func-example.c
init_defs_builtins: /usr/lib/coccinelle/standard.h
HANDLING: code/func-example.c
diff = 
--- code/func-example.c
+++ /tmp/cocci-output-182962-142650-func-example.c
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
-int baz() { return 3; }
+int baz(void) { return 3; }

-int main() {
+int main(void) {
   int var = baz();

   baz();

